# Javascript new Regexp не находит совпадение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, допустим есть текст:

> itemsview_226=%2B; itemsview_227=%2B; usersview_2=%2B;
>   jv_close_time_27t4wRIOv4=1522243008801; online=186;
>   lastvisit_Admin=1522253437; _gat_gtag_UA_101360848_2=1;
>   jv_pages_count_27t4wRIOv4=470

Делаем: `a.match(/online=(\w+)/g)` и находим `["online=186"]`

Теперь делаем так:

```
reg = new RegExp('online=(\w+)', 'g');
console.log(str.match(reg));
```

И находим **null**. Что не так?

Comment: экранирование слеша `\\` надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратный слэш необходимо экранировать (`\\w+`):

```js
const str = 'jv_close_time_27t4wRIOv4=1522243008801; online=186; lastvisit_Admin=1522253437;';

let re = new RegExp('online=(\\w+)', 'g');
document.body.textContent = str.match(re);
```

Экранирование необходимо по той причине, что в конструктор `RegExp` передается параметр *строкового типа* - а в строках, символ `\` является служебным: он используется для вывода спецсимволов (например, `\n`), и, собственно, для экранирования тех символов и последовательностей, которые могут быть интерпретированы как специальные.
В вашем случае, последовательность `\w` была обработана как экранирование символа `w`:  выражение приобрело вид `online=(w+)`, что и приводило к неожиданному результату.

В случае литеральной записи регулярного выражения (то есть, при записи вида `/online=(\w+)/g` ) - экранировать обратный слэш не нужно, так как при этом сразу создается экземпляр объектного типа `RegExp`:

```js
let re = /\w/i;
document.body.textContent = `Тип экземпляра рег.выражения при литеральной записи - ${typeof re}, а его класс - ${re.constructor.name}`;
```

Comment: опередил, плюсану.

Comment: `Слэш необходимо экранировать` а где развернутый ответ почему его необходимо тут экранировать, а тут `/online=(\w+)/g` нет?

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как сделать чтобы вернулся массив совпадений? Если конкретно, то мне нужно получить то что находится после =, в нашем случае число 186.

Comment: @Visman Пытался ( ) скобочки добавлять в разные места, безрезультатно.

Comment: @Владимир, в строке может быть несколько записей `online=?`? В хроме сработает так: `/(?<=online=)\w+/g`

Comment: @Владимир, используйте метод `RegExp.exec()` - он возвращает массив совпадений. Почитать об этом методе можно на MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: Точнее, `exec` возвращает *массив значений, извлеченных скобочными группами* регулярки, начиная с индекса 1 (нулевой элемент массива содержит полное совпадение с выражением). С флагом `g` в выражении, каждый последующий вызов `exec` будет возвращать следующий результат - пока не будет достигнут конец строки (и тогда вернется `null`).

Comment: @yar85 спасибо, exec метод помог. Странно что прошлый не сработал, ведь в документации написано что скобочки ( ) сохраняют значение, и возвращают массив из них.

Comment: Метод `match` возвращает отдельные значения из групп скобок, только если регулярка *без* флага `g`. А с этим флагом, возвращается массив полных совпадений с выражением. Проще говоря: с `g` - массив всех полных совпадений, а без `g`- массив содержащий только первое совпадение (по индексу 0 полное, и начиная с индекса 1 элементы значений из скобочных групп).